# string formation fails in postgresql function declaration

Tags: string, postgresql, casting, sql-function

I have created a function in sql which I call on separate chunks of a very large table.

I added a column `chunk` with values 0-to-4 (`int` typed column) and want to apply the function to the table chunk by chunk.

Here's the sql I am trying to parameterize:

```
update some_t t
    set col_2 = (select t2.col_2 from some_t t2
                 where t2.col_1 = t. col_1 
                 and t2.col_2 is not null
                 limit 1)
where t.col_2 is null;
```

Here's the function, with the additional argument `chunk`, which will allow me to partition the function on chunks of the table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION impute_place(table_ text, impute_from_col text, impute_to_col text, chunk text)
RETURNS VOID
AS $func$

BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || table_ || ' t1
             SET ' || impute_to_col || ' = (select t2.' || impute_to_col ||
                                            ' from ' || table_ || ' t2
                                             where t2.' || impute_from_col || ' = t1.' || impute_from_col ||
                                            ' and t2.' || impute_to_col || ' is not null
                                             limit 1)
             WHERE t1.' || impute_to_col || ' is null
             AND chunk = ' || chunk ||;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

When I try to run it subsequently on all partitions I get an error I tried to fix but cannot.

Also, without the `AND chunk = ' || chunk ||;` the function works perfectly, so the erro must be in this line!

```
select impute_place('some_t', 'col_1', 'col_2', '0');
select impute_place('some_t', 'col_1', 'col_2', '1');
select impute_place('some_t', 'col_1', 'col_2', '2');
select impute_place('some_t', 'col_1', 'col_2', '3');
select impute_place('some_t', 'col_1', 'col_2', '4');
```

I get the following error:

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: 
text || Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
You might need to add explicit type casts.
Where: PL/pgSQL function impute_place(text,text,text,text) line 4 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: Remove the void concatenation after `chunk`, i.e. `... || chunk ||;` should read `... || chunk;`.

Comment: And as a side note: `chunk` seems to be numeric. So the type of it should be a numeric type and not `text`. For the other variables `name` would fit better.

Comment: THANK YOU. It worked. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it so you get the points! :)